# How to create phonetic language model for CMU Sphinx?

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I need make phonetic recognition for russian. I followed tutorial from [project page](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/phonemerecognition).

In the tutorial I see

> You can take a text, convert it to a phonetic strings using the phonetic dictionary for your langauge. Just replace the words with their corresponding transcription. Since number of phones is small, text shouldn't be big either, just a book will do.

But where I can find phonetic dictionary? How I can replace the words with their corresponding transcription in whole book?

Or..where I can find complete phonetic model?

**UPDATED**

I created file test.txt with line:

*SIL i0 lj j a1 i1 lj f j e0 v gj e1 nj i0 j pj e0 t r o1 v z o0 l o0 t o1 j tj e0 lj o1 n o0 k SIL*

This is the line form test wav file with replaced russian words to phonetic reprezentation form dictionary (ru.dic).

Then I used SRILM to build mode with command:

*ngram-count -interpolate -text test.txt -lm test.phonetic.lm*

Next I start it with command:

*pocketsphinx\bin\Debug\Win32\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -samprate 16000 -allphone testModel\test.phonetic.lm -hmm cmusphinx-ru-5.2 -remove_noise no -infile testModel\decoder-test.wav -backtrace yes*

But when I use it I see incorrect result with wrong phonems.

Answer (score 0):

> But where I can find phonetic dictionary?

File ru.dic inside

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Russian/cmusphinx-ru-5.2.tar.gz/download

> How I can replace the words with their corresponding transcription in whole book?

With a script in Python

> Or..where I can find complete phonetic model?

You have to create it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, can you describe it more? I still can't do it.

Comment: You need to ask a new question on new topic and provide the data files to reproduce your problems.